# linq with Include and criteria

Tags: linq, entity-framework

How would I translate this into LINQ?

Say I have A parent table (Say, customers), and  child (addresses).
I want to return all of the Parents who have addresses in California, and just the california address. (but I want to do it in LINQ and get an object graph of Entity objects)

Here's the old fashioned way:

```
SELECT c.blah, a.blah
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Address a on c.CustomerId = a.CustomerId
where a.State = 'CA'
```

The problem I'm having with LINQ is that i need an object graph of concrete Entity types (and it can't be lazy loaded.

Here's what I've tried so far:

**Edit: added context instantiation as requested**

```
// this one doesn't filter the addresses -- I get the right customers, but I get all of their addresses, and not just the CA address object.

var ctx = new CustomersContext() // dbContext -- using EF 4.1 

from c in ctx.Customer.Include(c => c.Addresses)
where c.Addresses.Any(a => a.State == "CA")
select c

// this one seems to work, but the Addresses collection on Customers is always null
var ctx = new CustomersContext() // dbContext -- using EF 4.1 
from c in ctx.Customer.Include(c => c.Addresses)
from a in c.Addresses
where a.State == "CA"
select c;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As per @reddog's answer, please add the declaration and instantiation code for Customer, if you've previously loaded it, the result will be different from if it is just a reference to the context

Comment: @Ben Laan:  Sorry -- I pulled the code from LINQPad -- I'll add the instantiation, but there was no previous load -- the query is being run from a stateless web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code above, it appears that you already have a rehydrated collection of Customer objects in the `Customer` variable.

You will need to call the `Include` function when you fill your `Customer` collection above. This way, the framework will rehydrate the included objects at the time of retrieval from your data context.

The actual query code appears good though.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you provide a code example.  I tried wrapping the second query in parens, and then calling include on the result.  That returned my customers and addresses BUT -- I got all of the addresses for the selected customers.  I only want the California addresses.